# Join a room by a hash (string)

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I am trying to solve the following problem: People can connect to a room and every 5 seconds 2  people are randomly selected from this room to start a game (if at least 2 people are in the room). The game is a new room.

So I am joining the people to waiting room with `io['client'].join('waitingRoom');` and saving his ID `io['client']['id']` to the database (So basically I save a string like `'Dde7Wp41kf0EA3r3AAAA'` in the database).

I have a task which is running every 5 seconds which randomly selects 2 IDs from the database and the problem is that I do not know how to add these 2 IDs in the new `'game'` room. I have only a hash (some string) and not a socket object. Can I do this?

Comment: Glancing through the source, I don't see a good way to fetch a socket by ID. You may have to store IDs -> Sockets in an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the connected object of io.sockets. It stores sockets, you can retrieve them by id.

http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#connected:object

Example:

```
io.sockets.connected[socketIoID].emit('message', {data: 'test'});
```